# Generate functions and stored procedures from conceptual model Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I want to generate database from conceptual model (Ado.net entity data model). However when I generate database from model, it generates only the tables not the functions or stored procedures.

How can I deal with that? I use Entity Framework 6.